# OpenCv putext not working inisde if block

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, zbar

I'm trying to display some text on a frame which is being captured by OpenCV and the text has to be displayed only if certain condition is true, So that's why I placed `cv2.putText` inside the `if` condition. The code successfully reaches inside the `if` block but for some unknown reason the text doesn't get displayed, I've even put `waitKey` to pause the `VideoCapture frame` for a couple of seconds so that the screen pauses and to make the text noticeable when it gets displayed. The code is running fine without any errors. But that one thing that I wanna achieve is not working! Can anyone please help me with this? Below's the code snippet (There's more to the code but that part's unnecessary and this is the main region of the code which is not working as intended)

```
if(success != None):                
                    print('Inside if')
                    success = str(success)
                    l = len(success)

                    identify_query = 'SELECT * FROM student_data WHERE roll_no = %s'

                    cursor.execute(identify_query,(success[2:l-1],))

                    auth_res = cursor.fetchone()

                    if auth_res == None :
                        cv2.putText(frame,'No Such Record!',(50,50),font,2,(0,0,255),3)
                        cv2.waitKey(2000)  

                    elif success[2:l-1] not in records:
                        cv2.putText(frame,'Successfully Logged!',(50,50),font,2,(0,255,0),3) 
                        cv2.waitKey(2000) 

                    elif success[2:l-1] in records:
                        cv2.putText(frame,'Already Logged!',(50,50),font,2,(0,0,255),3)
                        cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

Comment: Possibly, you have a while loop and its updating pure image quickly and you dont notice displayed text. It can be better to share whole code

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I just found out it was just a stupid mistake, I was trying to put text after doing the ``cv2.imshow()``! Btw thanks! :)